# Generate consecutive number as title using auto_nodetitle?

Tags: nodes

I need that new submissions for an specific content type have a consecutive number as title. Found auto_nodetitle, but I don't know how to make it a consecutive number, they don't give clear instruccions as how to program it. I'm fairly new to Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed Token module, do so.

From there, you can insert the token [node:nid] into the auto title field. If you don't want to use the nid, you can install the Serial field module, add a field to the content type, and insert that into the title via [node:field_machine_name]. For most purposes, nid should suffice.

You can browse & insert token values via the supplied token browser ui.